# Firebase Platform triggers for cloud messaging

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

So basically in my flutter project there is need like if XYZ document is updated or modified then I need to send a push notification in android and IOS. So I want to know that is there any firebase function that can send a push notification when document is update/modify. I have Implemented Messaging for android and IOS in flutter and by providing Device token I can receive push notification in android. I have not tested it for IOS. but the thing is it should not be done by human. I mean it should trigger automatically when any kind of update is done on document. also I want to know that for that I need to create any kind of web platform or can I write it directly to the firebase console?

I have also read one documentation regarding Cloud Firestore Triggers. But in which they mentioned that method using Node.js and Python. But I want know is it possible through directly from Firebase?

[Link for Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events?gen=2nd#node.js)

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct connection between Firestore and Firebase Cloud Messaging, but you can write a Cloud Function for this. In fact, [notifying the user when something interesting happens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases#notify_users_when_something_interesting_happens) is the first use-case in the documentation for that - and it looks like this:

[image]

So here, a notification is sent through FCM when a user gets a new follower. The [code for this specific example](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/main/Node/fcm-notifications) triggers on writes to Realtime Database, but you can [trigger on writes to Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events) in almost the same way.